# Beginner at nodeJS... using WAMP

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

OK, so I installed nodeJS and I am using WAMP. I go to CMD and type `node`. It works. Here's my problem:

[image: Test.]

As you can see, it it does not.. when I try to test `hello.js`. I am a complete newb... please help me out here?

However, I *do* know PHP and JavaScript... but it's just that nodeJS is... not so nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you trying to start hello.js from node REPL (read-evaluate-print console ). Just exit from REPL (double ctrl+c) and type in shell command prompt "node hello.js"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're copying the commands verbatim, including the (Unix) shell prompt. Try ctrl-d or ctrl-z then enter to get out the Node comkand line interface and return to cmd.exe and try your command again.

Comment: I got this: http://codepad.org/jTbiaDir Hmm I even tried with the `node` before the `c:\wamp\www\........`

Comment: node and the file has to be on the same line, otherwise you're in the javascript console